# What's a tuple in normal English?

Tags: meaning

A *tuple* in mathematics is a sequence of numbers (n1, n2, n3).

In databases, a *tuple* is a single row of data from a table.

What is a *tuple* in normal everyday English, or where does the word come from?  Is there a concrete real-life object from which this word is derived?  WordNet does not have a definition.

Comment: Would be nice if someone mentioned how they pronounce is right? I've heard people say _"two-ple"_ a lot though.

Comment: @giddy, someone thought the same as you: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-pronounce-tuple

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The word derives from the extended series of single, double, triple, quadruple, quintuple,..., where named multiples beyond five are generally words that end in "tuple". The natural (Latin-derived) words peter out pretty quickly, and mathematics needs more terms than a simple bipedal meat unit can easily memorize, so the term "*n*-tuple" was coined. Computer science took that ball and ran with it, dropping the "*n*-" altogether.

In other words, "tuple" has no meaning in everyday English.

Comment: I would rate your explanation better. :)

Comment: There are also _sextuple_, _septuple_, and _octuple_.

Comment: @kiam Theoretically, you could continue that line ad infinitum.  But in reality, no-one is that masochistic. ;-)

Comment: @jae You mean, infinitytuple

Comment: @kiam Most people try to avoid saying sextuple.

Comment: @bobobobo: It could be, but that is their problem if they think the word is related to sex in any way. **:-)**

Comment: @ikartik90, better than what?

Answer (score 21):

**Nothing**. The word *tuple* is back-formed from Latinisms like *quintuple*, and it is only used in technical contexts. The average English speaker has never heard the word, and it has no meaning outside of the context of mathematics or software engineering.

Comment: I think it's actually a double back formation.  I've seen _n-tuple_ more commonly used in older texts, and _tuple_ in newer texts.

Comment: Man.  So people who say its pronounced "too-ple" (instead of "tuh-ple") are really off the rocker?

Comment: Off the rocker we may be, but 'tuh-ple' would be more naturally spelled 'tupple'. As one who had never put explicit thought into the before, I naturally pronounced 'too-ple'. Is there a consensus? (we're back-forming words afterall!)

Comment: @bobobobo - in British English people are most likely to say "quin-too-pl" rather than "quin-tuh-pl" anyway, so "too-pl" has that going for it anyway. Plus zourtney's good point about the spelling.

Comment: I'd like to make a note about pronunciation. I am British and I say 'tuh-ple' rather than 'too-ple' for words like 'quintuple'. Furthermore, I have never heard 'too-ple' from anyone else. Even 'quintuplets' and the like I would pronounce with a 'tuh' rather than a 'too' and so would anyone else I know.