# How to pronounce "tuple"?

Tags: pronunciation

A [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12891/whats-a-tuple-in-normal-english) has reminded me of something I’ve been wondering about for a while: what is the correct way to pronounce *tuple*?

Comment: What is a non-mathematical example of this?

Comment: I don’t know what “correct” means, but the three most frequent pronunciations used by native speakers are `[ˈtʰʌpɫ̩]`, `[ˈtʰupɫ̩]`, and `[ˈtʰjupɫ̩]`.

Comment: looks like nobody agrees - how does the creator say it, thats what they had to do with linux to get everyone to shut up about it. But, the originator of the word is probably long since dead... so can we make up our own rules then?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been answered. An answer has been accepted. The alternative pronunciations are agreed. All discussion is now subjective and/or opinion.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There are two possible pronunciations, one to rhyme with *two pull* (/tupəl/) and the other with *supple* (/tʌpəl/).

Take your pick. There will always be someone to agree with you... [violently](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/how-is-sql-pronounced) :)

Comment: How to rhyme _tuple_ with _two_?

Comment: @Tim, to or too if you prefer :)

Comment: @Benjol: So we're talking about _that_ syllable...

Comment: You say a Tuple and I say a Tuple ;)

Comment: Just being picky here, but "two pull" and "tuple" are not perfect rhymes, since "pull" is [pʊl] and the "ple" in "tuple" is [pəl].

Comment: @Kosmo, fair point. To be honest, I don't often have occasion to say 'tuple' either way.

Comment: In dialects of English that have not experienced [yod dropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yod_dropping) (and still make a distinction between the words _dew_ and _do_, such as [RP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)), you will also hear `/tjupəl/`, which is how I would pronounce the word. I have often (in London) heard `/tupəl/`, though I have never heard `/tʌpəl/`. (I'm [with tchrist](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-pronounce-tuple#comment32001_12981) on that one ;o)

Comment: I've always pronounced it two-ple. In Python programming circles you'll find proponents of both forms - and usually we're pretty accepting of each other's craziness ;)

Comment: There are three common pronunciations: `[ˈtʰʌpɫ̩]`, `[ˈtʰupɫ̩]`, and `[ˈtʰjupɫ̩]`.

Answer (score 56):

It should be pronounced to rhyme with *quintuple*, *sextuple*, *octuple* etc, since these are its origins.

Comment: This is how I've heard it pronounced in the USA (except that I would leave "quadruple" off the list since the "u" there is long). This one may be subject to some regional differences, given @Ham and Bacon's answer.

Comment: @JeffSahol: You're right that there are regional differences: for example the "u" is long in "quintuple", "sextuple" is long in British English. Saying it's "like quintuple" is about right, because although in my experience there's quite a lot of variation in how people say that word, exactly the same variation occurs with "tuple" :-)

Comment: The pronunciation analogy with 'quintuple' etc. won't necessarily work because of of how stress modifies vowels. There could also be a competing analogy with 'double'.

Comment: So next question. What is the correct pronunciation of those three words!

Comment: Well, sure, but then you are purposefully excluding quadruple (quadroople, not quadrupple), which conveniently breaks the mold. I think the more complete answer here lies in the phonetics of the prefix of the word. When the prefix (ends in?) a soft/non-consonant sound (or non-existent), the 'u' should go long vs short. ie: 'qua' is different from 'quin', 'sex', 'sept, 'oct'. Now, if Tuple were instead Tuplet, I would go with the 'upplet' :-o!

Comment: I agree with this answer. 'Tuple' should rhyme with 'quadruple.' Hence /tupəl/.

Comment: Please expand your answer. How do you pronounce _quintuple_? Bear in mind that not everybody around is a native English speaker.

Comment: Quintuple is pronounced /tʌpəl/
Quadruple is the lonely one, pronounced /tupəl/ or maybe /tjupl/

There is no 'correct' way, it's ambiguous in English.

Comment: Okay, so how do you pronounce _quintuple_, _sextuple_, etc., since I've heard those pronounced either way as well?

Comment: @MartinSmith Those three words are pronounced like 'tuple'

Answer (score 29):

I don't use either of the pronunciations Benjol mentioned. I say /tjupl/, the first syllable rhyming with "stew".

I suspect that Benjol has a dialect in which "dew" and "do" are homonyms, but they aren't for me or most British speakers.

Comment: Really? I've never heard anyone in England say "tewple" - it's always "toople".

Comment: (Or, in one instance, "tupple").

Comment: You may never have heard it. But I assure you that on the rare occasions when I say the word I pronounce it /tjupl/, like "tulip" and "tutor". Why the downvote?

Comment: "Most British speakers" certainly does not accord with my observation.

Comment: @Marcin My guess is that you have observed British programmers using the American pronunciation, but this is the traditional British one.

Comment: @Marcin: I didn't say anything about how most British speakers pronounce "tuple": I said how I pronounce the word, and made a subsidiary comment about how British speakers pronounce "do" and "dew".

Comment: I'm British and also rhyme it with "tulip" and "tutor"

Comment: interestingly, i can hear both ways in India. And i prefer tuple over tuple

Answer (score 22):

When I first heard of *tuple* in C.J. Date’s book *An Introduction to Database Systems*, he goes to the trouble of explaining that it is pronounced like *couple*. That was in an early edition around 1983.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that Date has any right to pontificate, but +1 for actually providing some evidence, rather than 'this is what I do'.

Answer (score 13):

I am a British speaker.

I pronounce Dew and Do differently (dew - stew - chew / do - too - who).

But tuple/quintuple/quintuplets I pronounce with 'up', not 'oop' (tuple - supple).

So do any other British speakers I know.

Comment: The "dew"/"do" distinction you are referring to is because UK English allows the /j/ [onglide](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on-glide) to occur after [coronal consonants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_consonant), /t,d,s,z/ and so on. Although both AmE and BrE can distinguish "fool" /ful/ and "fuel" /fjul/, AmE treats both "dew" /dju/ and "do" /du/ as /du/.

Comment: Yes, @kosmonaut, that is quite right. I used the other words to try to provide 'sounds like' examples for my own pronunciation in the absence of IPA symbols. (I've seen them used on here but I don't know how people do it)

Comment: @Karl: IPA symbols are easy. Just open up a page that already has them and use murine snarf-N-barf to insert whatever you need.

Comment: Oh, just like that? Excellent, thanks. ( @tchrist )

Comment: Really? Every programmer I have met in England says "toople".

Comment: Actually, I knew one guy at university who insisted on saying "tupple". He was from Oxford.

Comment: @Marcin: clearly you haven't met the programmers I've met.  Then again, what can you expect from Oxford?  (Says the Cantabrigian :-)

Comment: @Rhodri: Are you saying that you and your programmers say "tewple"? Is it because you're Welsh, or a Cambridge thing?

Comment: @Marcin: I don't have a Welsh accent (I'm from Herefordshire originally), and I don't believe it's purely a Cambridge thing.  I'm quite prepared to believe that different regions of the UK use the /j/ onglide to different extents, though.

Answer (score 8):

From [dictionary.com:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tuple)

> tjʊp ə l, ˈtʌp ə l)

So, the actual pronunciation is actually either "tew-pel" or "tu-" as in "but".

Comment: Isn't /ˈtʌpəl/ more like "tupple" than "tew-pel" or "too-pel"?

Comment: My pronounciation guide puts it as "ʌ" as in "but"!! I always said "but" as in "boot"... Jks. Don't know what happened when I posted that answer.

Comment: /tjʊp ə l/ is yet another pronunciation, that nobody else has mentioned. I say /tjup ə l/ with a tense /u/ not a lax /ʊ/

Comment: @ColinFine I would say that /tjʊpəl/ is almost certainly a typo. Stressed /jʊ/ is not a phonotactically valid sequence in any type of English I’m familiar with, except just _possibly_ as a variant of /yud yəd/ for ‹you’d› (and there it’s probably just the result of allophonic lengthening of the schwa before a voiced plosive, as is regular).

Answer (score 4):

#### *Tuple* can be pronounced as “tewple”/"toople” or “tupple”

Broadly speaking, there are two main pronunciations of *tuple:* “tewple” and “tupple”. Neither one is incorrect, so there is no single correct way to pronounce this word. As [Ed Guiness says in his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31726/77227), it is derived from the end of *quintuple, sextuple, octuple* etc. and the same variation exists in the pronunciation of these words.

By “tupple” I mean /tʌpəl/, a pronunciation which is more or less the same all mainstream accents of English.

By “tewple” I mean a pronunciation that starts the same way as “Tuesday”, a word whose pronunciation varies by accent:

- /tjuːpəl/ “tyoople” like /tjuːz/ ("tyooz")-*day* in accents that maintain word-initial /tj/ clusters
- /tʃuːpəl/“chewple” like /tʃuːz/ ("choose")-*day* in accents that change word-initial /tj/ to /tʃ/
- /tuːpəl/ “toople” like /tuːz/ ("tooz")-*day* in accents that drop /j/ after word-initial /t/.

However, one [commenter on this page, Marcin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-pronounce-tuple#comment57118_13026), has indicated that he uses and is used to hearing "toople" even in a British English context (in England), and there are three upvotes for his comment.

If a non-negligible portion of British English speakers pronounce *tuple* as "toople", with a different start from the word *tutor* "tyooter/chooter", an explanation could be influence from hearing American English speakers pronounce the word.

It's unclear to me how widespread the pronunciation with /tu/ "too" might be for speakers that otherwise don't drop the sound /j/ after /t/ in words spelled with *tu-*. A subsequent [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-pronounce-tuple#comment394354_13026) by [Scott Earle](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/27183/scott-earle), also currently with three upvotes, says "I'm British and also rhyme it with "tulip" and "tutor" (Aug 6, 2014).

#### “Tewple” is more regular, going from the spelling

The “tewple” pronunciation is more regular. (This doesn’t necessarily mean it is more correct, but some people might think it’s relevant.) In words of Latin origin, the letter “u” usually corresponds to the “long u” sound when it comes before a single consonant letter and a vowel letter, or before a consonant letter followed by “r” or “l” and then a vowel letter (e.g. *n**u**cleus, n**u**trient, d**u**plex, J**u**piter*).

#### However, *tuple* = “tupple” is not an unprecedented sound-spelling correspondence

There are a small number of exceptions to this rule about the pronunciation of "u" before a single consonant followed by a vowel letter or the letter "r" or "l", so the pronunciation “tupple”, while less regular than “tewple”, does have some precedent.

For some words, an exceptional pronunciation with “short u” is only used by some speakers. Some of these exceptional pronunciations have been criticized by prescriptivists. (See the entry for “[c**u**linary](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtojrMr0Ft4C&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=book%20of%20beastly%20mispronunciations%20culinary%20properly&source=bl&ots=FMJISOfnvi&sig=05LsQAgSiY4n1aCFktrttF0G0_c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38_D-g5TSAhWH6YMKHTefDBIQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=book%20of%20beastly%20mispronunciations%20culinary%20properly&f=false)” in “The Big Book of Beastly Mispronunciations”, by Charles Harrington Elster, who seems to view the pronunciation with /ʌ/ with a kind of resigned acceptance. The two other words I know of that are variable between “long u” and “short u” like this are *j**u**gular* and *tr**u**culent,* although I haven't come across any prescriptive references that talk about them).

But there are other words like this where “short u” is the only possible vowel, rather than an optional variant. These mainly came into English through French (*ducat, punish, public, publish, study*) although there are also Latinate words taken from French that regularly have “long u” (such as *soluble, voluble*; the quality of the actual vowel in these words may be reduced to /ʊ/ or /ə/ since it's in an unstressed syllable, but the glide /j/ preceding the vowel makes it clear that it is underlyingly “long u”).

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the word *quintuple* did come into English from French, so I see no clear etymological basis for considering it incorrect to pronounce it with either the vowel of “sol**u**ble” or of “p**u**blic”.

#### “Tupple” is probably aided by analogy with *single, double, triple*

One important factor that has probably influenced the pronunciation of this word is analogy. The first British pronunciations given by the Oxford English Dictionary for *quadruple, quintuple, sextuple* actually have the stress on the first syllable. However, for American English it shows second-syllable stress. This probably developed by analogy with the stress pattern of the words *single, double, triple,* which all have penultimate stress. Another example of analogy among this set of words is the use of the *-et* suffix originally found in *doublet* (a word taken from French) to form *triplet, quadruplet, quintuplet* etc.

*Single, double, triple* all have short vowels, and this probably contributed to the use of a short vowel in *quintuple* etc. (I don’t know why the vowel of *quadruple* has apparently been immune to this influence.)

Comment: If "tupple" really is a correct pronunciation, I need to stop laughing whenever I hear people say it.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little surprised to hear two people who sounded like Brits (Tim Isted and Dave Addey) both saying "tupple" in the "Introduction to Swift" session (402) at Apple's WWDC 2014. (Unfortunately, this is not public.) Like Colin Fine, above, I've always said /tjuple/, and thought that was standard in the UK. Then again, Tim and Dave work for Apple, so maybe they've adopted a company standard.

On "tjuple" vs. "toople": my guess is that this is the same UK vs. US variation as we see with "stew".

Comment: There are three common pronunciations: `[ˈtʰʌpɫ̩]`, `[ˈtʰupɫ̩]`, and `[ˈtʰjupɫ̩]`.

Comment: @njr0 In the "Intermediate Swift" session (403) from WWDC 2014, Brian Lanier uses the "tew-pel" pronunciation. So I don't think they have agreed on anything internally at Apple :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of many online dictionaries out there that can help you with this. I suggest you click on the links and listen to the pronunciations yourself, when available.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tuple)

> ### [tuple](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tuple)
>
> noun [ C ] /ˈtuː.pl/ /ˈtjuːpəl/ /ˈtuːpəl/

---

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tuple)

> ### [tuple](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tuple)
>
> /ˈtjuːp(ə)l/

---

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuple) says

> #### Origin and Etymology of -[tuple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuple)
>
> quin*tuple*, sex*tuple*

Now looking at one of them, say [quintuple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quintuple) on the same dictionary, we get

> ### [quintuple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quintuple)
>
> \kwin-ˈtü-pəl, -ˈtyü-, -ˈtə-; ˈkwin-tə-\

---

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tuple): Lists two different pronunciations

> ### [tuple](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tuple)
>
> (to͞o′pəl, tŭp′əl)
> (ˈtjʊpəl; ˈtʌpəl)

---

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tuple_1)

> ### [tuple](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tuple_1)
>
> ˈtjʊp<sup>ə</sup>l  , ˈtʌp<sup>ə</sup>l

---

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tuple?s=t)

> ### [tuple](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tuple?s=t)
>
> /ˈtjʊpəl; ˈtʌpəl/

---

[WordReference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/tuple)

> ### [tuple](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/tuple)
>
> /ˈtjʊp<sup>ə</sup>l/
> /ˈtjʊp<sup>ə</sup>l; ˈtʌp<sup>ə</sup>l/

---

#### My conclusion:

I prefer the first three dictionaries listed, naturally, and sometimes Collins. The first three consistently say that, pronunciationg of "tu" part of tuple is as in "stew" or "tool", but not rhyming with "but". More importantly, as said in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuple), and also as did [Ed Guiness in his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31726/99796), "tuple" should rhyme with its origins- quintuple, sextuple, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Should be pronounced "too'pəl" the way the dear Loord intended, unless you're joost being stoobborn.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, so much for sarcasm. Haters gonna hate. Personally, I have always pronounced it as "tupple" (like "couple") and I'm pretty sure that's the way I've mostly heard it during my career.

Comment: I understand it's not a conforming answer, but I appreciated your levity.