# How do you pronounce "tuple"?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pronounce “tuple”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-pronounce-tuple)

I had always thought tuple rhymes with "couple".
But I recently came across pronunciations like "tew-ple" and "too-ple". Which is right?

Comment: I feel this question is too general for this site, and it's a duplicate.

Comment: Good question, just a duplicate or general reference.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but the answer by @Ed is the clearest for both, IMO.