# Is there a word like cardinal or ordinal but for the “single, double, triple” series?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, numbers

The words *one, two, three,* and so on are the ***cardinal* numbers**.

Similarly, *first, second, third,* and so on are the 
***ordinal* numbers**.

Is there a similar term for the words *single, double, triple*, and all the rest?

Comment: Not sure but "multiple" as in *what multiple of.....*?

Comment: Some related but different questions:  [What's a tuple in normal English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12891), and  [How can I form a word like “quadruple” for any number I want?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5475), and   [Is there a system for creating words for ordinal numbers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15550),

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160282/a-term-that-describes-high-order-ordinal-numbers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are called *multiplicatives* by [Fowler (1850)](http://books.google.com/books?id=QMosAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA215&lpg=PA215&dq=english%20numerals%20single%20double%20triple&source=bl&ots=_rVdKDPKHm&sig=Bkj8aSpH7oKiq-otuUojM_kwAiM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=znxgUYzzJO242QXL9YHgBg&ved=0CGgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=english%20numerals%20single%20double%20triple&f=false). The term *multiplicative* is also seen to describe the words *once, twice, thrice*, and it seems reasonable to distinguish the former as *multiplicative adjectives,* and the latter as *multiplicative adverbs*.

Comment: Oh wow, a treasure trove. Great answer!

Comment: See also Wikipedia's [English numerals § Multiplicative adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Multiplicative_adverbs), which covers adverbs and multiple forms of adjectives.

Comment: Actually, on page 215, Fowler identifies _once_, _twice_, and _thrice_ as "numeral adverbs," not as _multiplicatives_.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be.

Wikipedia says they are called "tuples" and associates them with ordered sets, but this language is specific to mathematics.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple

There is no definition of "tuple" in *Merriam-Webster*, though there is a definition for the noun combining form "-tuple." It is the "set of (so many) elements —usually used of sets with ordered elements ."

There is no explanation in the *Chicago Manual of Style*, though rule 12.29 refers to the "ordered n-tuple of objects," which seems again to be a particular, technical usage.

Comment: -1 Tuple refers to the set (or sequence) itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Dave is right; there does not seem to be a term or name for this sequence.

So why not have a little fun inventing one? If *cardinal* refers to *power* or *amount* (one, two, three), and if *ordinal* refers to *position* (first, second, third), then *single, double, triple* would be referring to a mathematical relationship. We might invent a term such as *multipal*, but that would be confused with *multiple*. And *multiplal* would be terribly awkward. So how about *relational*? *The relational numbers.* Doesn't sound too bad. But, hey, it's just a suggestion.