# What is the name for the group of words that includes "once", "twice", and "thrice"?

Tags: grammar, terminology, numbers

If "one", "two", and "three" are *cardinal* numbers, and "first", "second", and "third" are *ordinal* numbers, then what are "once", "twice", and "thrice"? Is there a name for this kind of number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word like cardinal or ordinal but for the “single, double, triple” series?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110635/is-there-a-word-like-cardinal-or-ordinal-but-for-the-single-double-triple-se)

Comment: Not really a duplicate question, even if the answer happens to be the same.

Comment: Instead of saying "one time", "two times", "three times", these words are used to  denote the number of occurrences of some event.

Comment: I know what they mean, that's not the question.

Comment: @Jim: The question here is addressed in the same book that is cited in the question you link to, but the answer is different for the two types of terms. Consequently I think that these are closely related but not duplicate questions.

Comment: *finger hovers over "duplicate of" for what seems like an interminable time*....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One longtime term for this group of words is **numeral adverb**. William C. Fowler, [*English Grammar: The English Language in Its Elements and Forms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QMosAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA215&dq=%22NUMERAL+ADVERBS,+which+answer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigo_XC1rLLAhURymMKHfvrAvo4ChDoAQgyMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22NUMERAL%20ADVERBS%2C%20which%20answer%22&f=false) (1850) uses this nomenclature:

> § 193. NUMERALS express the relation of Number and Quantity. They are divided into the following classes:
>
> ...
>
> IV. **NUMERAL ADVERBS**, which answer the question *How often?* as, *Once*, *twice*, *thrice*, *four times*.

That terminology goes back to at least 1822, when it was used by Edward Everett, in his translation of Philipp Buttmann, [*Greek Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-TMQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22NUMERAL+ADVERBS,+which+answer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigo_XC1rLLAhURymMKHfvrAvo4ChDoAQhKMAg#v=onepage&q=%22NUMERAL%20ADVERBS%2C%20which%20answer%22&f=false).

The same terminology is used as recently as 2007, by Alexander Coupe, [*A Grammar of Mongsen Ao*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zCuxqyCW8yQC&pg=PA277&dq=%22numeral+adverbs%22+thrice&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjioe2C2LLLAhVM0GMKHZ-vB5EQ6AEIQjAG#v=onepage&q=%22numeral%20adverbs%22%20thrice&f=false) (2007):

> **Numeral adverbs** are derived by attaching the suffix *–pən* to the stem of a cardinal number. The **numeral adverb** *khən* ‘once’ is irregular, in common with both the distributive and ordinal derivations of ONE, and does not use this suffix to express its adverbial meaning. Apart from [a complication involving the word for ‘twice’], the derivations of the remaining **numeral adverbs** are completely regular, e.g. *à-sə̀m-pən* 'thrice', *phə̀lì-pən* 'four times', ...

---

**Update (April 19, 2022): *iterative* and *multiplicative numerals***

As longtime site participant Michael points out in a comment beneath this answer, Fowler changes his nomenclature in the revised and enlarged edition of [*English Grammar: The English Language in Its Elements and Forms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NxkAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA272&dq=%22iterative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic94LR8KD3AhWYHjQIHWKWBEsQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22iterative%20numerals%22&f=false) (1855) from *numeral adverb* to **iterative numeral**:

> § 280. I. CARDINAL NUMERALS, or Cardinals, which express number in its simplest form, and answer the question *How many?* as *One*, *two*, *three*, *four*, and so on indefinitely. ...
>
> ...
>
> 3. ***Iterative Numerals***; as, *Once*, *twice*, *thrice*. These are the genitives of the abstract numerals used adverbially. The series is continued by means of adverbial phrases; as, *Four times*, *five times*; and answers to the question *How often?*

All subsequent editions of Fowler's English Grammar, which appeared [as late as 1884](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hn4qve&view=1up&seq=274&skin=2021&q1=%22iterative%20numerals%22) used the term *iterative numerals*. I should perhaps note here that this Fowler is [William Chauncey Fowler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Chauncey_Fowler) (1793–1881), an American grammarian, not [Henry Watson Fowler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Watson_Fowler), the eminent British grammarian (1858–1933).

This term still occasionally appears, as in Michael Closs, [*Native American Mathematics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YFlfAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&dq=%22iterative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiftejIhqH3AhW3CjQIHdrSBvo4FBDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22iterative%20numerals%22&f=false) (2010):

> First, if events rather than things are being counted [in the Inuktitut language], the verb suffix *-iqtaq-*, 'do so many times', can be added to the number root, e.g., *pingasu-iqtaq-tuq*, 'he did it three times', -- such words are sometimes termed **iterative numerals**.
>
> ...
>
> When the roots for the **iterative numerals** are reduplicated [in the Ojibway language] an iterative distributive series is obtained (e.g., *neningoding*, 'once each'; *neniizhing*, 'twice each'; etc.).

Yet another term for this type of number is **multiplicative numeral**, as used (for example) in Nicholas Poppe, [*Grammar of Written Mongolian*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mVKR3Da2B7MC&pg=PA56&dq=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP5q2ihqH3AhX3HjQIHSf-DPoQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22multiplicative%20numerals%22&f=false) (1974):

> **Multiplicative Numerals**
>
> **201.** Suffix *-ta/-te*. Function: to form numerals meaning "one time", "two times or twice", etc.
>
> > *nigente* once | *qoyarta* twice | *yurbanta* three times | *dörbente* four times | *tabunta* five times
>
> Although *olan* "many" and *kedü* "how many" are not numerals, there exist the forms *olanta* "many times" and *kedünte* "how many times".
>
> **202.** Another form of the **multiplicative numerals** is that without the final consonant *n* of the cardinal form.
>
> > *nige* once | *qoyar* twice | *yurba* three times

However, Fowler, [writing in 1855](https://books.google.com/books?id=NxkAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA274&dq=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjej7aui6H3AhXVKkQIHRzJCcEQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22multiplicative%20numerals%22&f=false), applies the term *multiplicative numerals* to words of the form *single*, *double*, *triple*, etc.:

> III. **MULTIPLICATIVE NUMERALS**, or **Multiplicatives**, which show the number of parts of which a whole is composed, and answer the question *How many fold?* as *Single*, *double*, *triple*, or *treble*, *four-fold* or *quadruple*.

It follows that referring to words of the form *once*, *twice*, *thrice*, etc., as *multiplicative numerals* is problematic. Nevertheless, a number of authors have used the term in that sense. For example, from [U.S.] Army Language School, [*Serbo-Croatian Textbook*](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=uI1NAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Multiplicative+numerals+in+Serbo+-+Croatian%22) (1952) [relevant text not shown in snippet window]:

> 300 **MULTIPLICATIVE NUMERALS Multiplicative numerals** in Serbo-Croatian are formed : 1.- Cardinal numeral + пут in the proper case:
>
> > један пут once | два пута twice | три пута thrice, three times | четири пута four times ...

And from Stefan Wurm, [*Turkic Peoples of the USSR: Their Historical Background, Their Languages and the Development of Soviet Linguistic Policy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YfgsAAAAMAAJ&q=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&dq=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA7cKvj6H3AhX1oFsKHQ7MAUU4ChDoAXoECAsQAg) (1954) [snippet view]:

> [A]pproximative numerals are also found, for instance, "about ten", which in Uzbek would [word in Cyrillic alphabet] (on-te-çe ) etc. As a rule, however, there is no special category for expressing the concept rendered in English by the **multiplicative numerals** (e.g. "twice").

But other sources use the term in its Fowler-defined sense. For example, from Alfred Read, [*Balti Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YjEOAAAAYAAJ&q=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&dq=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih2Z_SjaH3AhWYITQIHay6B4kQ6AF6BAgGEAI) (1934) [combined snippets]:

> ***Multiplicative Numerals***
>
> The English suffix "fold", for instance "two-fold", "threefold", when meaning twice or thrice the amount already mentioned is very simply constructed in Balti by adding the word *zde* to the qualifying number.

And from Fred Householder, Kostas Kazazis & Andreas Koutsoudas, [*Reference Grammar of Literary Dhimotiki*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hW0LAAAAIAAJ&q=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&dq=%22multiplicative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA7cKvj6H3AhX1oFsKHQ7MAUU4ChDoAXoECAoQAg) (1964) [snippet view]:

> 3.5631. ***Multiplicative numerals***: These correspond to English "double", "triple", etc. They are regular adjectives in -(α)πλός, -(α)πλή, -(α)πλό , but are also frequently used as substantives.

Mario Pei & Frank Gaynor, [*Dictionary of Linguistics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xHmvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&dq=%22iterative+numerals%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj54ZqghaH3AhUdJzQIHVwcAA8Q6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22iterative%20numerals%22&f=false) (1954) offers this pair of relevant entries:

> **iterative numeral:** A numeral which answers the question "How many times?" (Also referred to as *multiplicative numeral*.)
>
> ...
>
> **multiplicative numeral:** A numeral which ansers the question "How many times?" or "How many fold?" (Some authorities classify also the *iterative* numerals as multiplicatives.)

This dictionary doesn't include an entry for *numeral adverb*, however.

On balance, it would seem wise to avoid *multiplicative numeral* in favor of either *numeral adverb* or *iterative numeral*, assuming that the choice came down to these three options.

Comment: No problem! This was an interesting answer; I had not heard of this term before.

Comment: Note: it seems that in the newer 1860 version of William Fowlers book, the expression "numeral adverbs" was renamed to _iterative numerals_: https://archive.org/details/englishgrammaren00fowl/page/272

Comment: It appears to have been used earlier for Latin grammar. "After a **numeral adverb** once, twice..." [William Walker, *A Treatise...*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Treatise_of_English_Particles_Shewing/sOAeapzhYSMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=numeral+adverbs+semel&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) (1720)